# then the value of $\alpha , \beta , \gamma$

Tags: analysis, proof-verification, numerical-methods

For an infinitely differentiable function $f$ and $h>0$, if the approximated derivative $$D_hf(x)=\frac{\alpha f(x)+\beta(f(x+h)-f(x-h))+\gamma(f(x+2h)-f(x-2h))}{h}$$

yields error $f'(x)-D_hf(x)=Ch^4$, where $C$ is a constant, then the value of $\alpha , \beta , \gamma$

I find the value of $\alpha=0 , \beta=2/3 , \gamma=\frac{-1}{12}$, Can someone please check that my answer is correct or not. Thanks.

Comment: Why not try it on an example, like plotting $g(h)=|1-D_h \exp(0)|$ on a log-log scale? Or you can have a CAS like Wolfram Alpha do a series expansion of $1-D_h \exp(0)$ for you.

Comment: I use Taylor series and find the results

Comment: I understand how you do the calculation, but you can check it by more directly inspecting whether $f'(x)-D_h f(x)=O(h^4)$ for a particular (non-polynomial but smooth) $f$, such that you know what $f'(x)$ is. A good benchmark is $\exp$. Thus your question can be basically reduced to: is $1-\frac{\exp(h)-\exp(-h)-\exp(2h)/4+\exp(-2h)/4}{h}=O(h^4)$?

Comment: Ok, I get ur point. Thanks